# Sum all values of drinking for a certain day

Tags: google-sheets

I'm creating a sheet for my baby milk consumption and I'm trying to have a sum of the milk drank each day.

Here is a picture of the sheet in question:
[image]

Now I don't know how to select the value in column C for each day! Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Would you be opposed to copying the date to cover each row? This would make it much simpler to create a summary for each day. You'd just have to use SUMIF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can repeat the date on every row, use `query()` to aggregate the quantities by day. Put this formula in cell `E1` or another free range outside of `A1:D`:

```
=query( 
  A1:D, 
  "select A, sum(C) 
   where A is not null 
   group by A", 
  0 
)
```

If you cannot repeat the date on each row for some reason, use an array formula to fill the dates down, like this:

```
=arrayformula( query( 
  { 
    if( 
      row(B1:B) <= max(row(B1:B) * (B1:B <> "")), 
      iferror( 
        vlookup( 
          row(A1:A), 
          if( len(A1:A), { row(A1:A), A1:A } ), 
          2, 
          true 
        ) 
      ), 
      iferror(1/0) 
    ), 
    B1:D 
  }, 
  "select Col1, sum(Col3) 
   where Col1 is not null 
   group by Col1", 
  1 
) )
```

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using a SUMIF:

```
=SUMIF(A:A; "="&G5; C:C)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

what you could do is

1.
Add the date in all cells in Column-a
(Ex. 5Mai 2022 from A50 to A55, 6 MAi 2022 form A51 to A63, and so on)

2. Use sumif function

This will solve the issue